# Prolog: Print all planets and moons

Tags: prolog

I want to get all planets **and** its moons `O` that are further away than planet `P`

```
% planets
orbits(mercury, sun).
orbits(venus, sun).
orbits(earth, sun).
orbits(mars, sun).
orbits(jupiter, sun).
orbits(saturn, sun).
orbits(uranus, sun).
orbits(neptune, sun).
ae(mercury, 0.39).
ae(venus, 0.72).
ae(earth, 1).
ae(mars, 1.52).
ae(jupiter, 5.20).
ae(saturn, 9.54).
ae(uranus, 19.22).
ae(neptune, 30.06).
% moons
orbits(moon, earth).
orbits(deimos, mars).
orbits(phobos, mars).
orbits(ganymede, jupiter).
orbits(callisto, jupiter).
orbits(io, jupiter).
orbits(europa, jupiter).
orbits(titan, saturn).
orbits(enceladus, saturn).
orbits(titania, uranus).
orbits(oberon, uranus).
orbits(umbriel, uranus).
orbits(ariel, uranus).
orbits(miranda, uranus).
orbits(triton, neptune).
```

First I tried to get all planets that are further away than `P`

```
outer_orbit(P,O):-ae(O,X),ae(P,Y),X>Y.
```

Now I need to print all Moons that are in `O`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I need to print all Moons that are in `O`
>
> How can I do that?

It seems a work for `findall/3`

```
findall(X, orbits(X, P), Lm)
```

where `P` is the planet and `Lm` is the list of the moons.

The "print" part can be a simple

```
write(Lm)
```

But in this way you can find also the list of the planets, with

```
findall(X, orbits(X, sun), Lp)
```

If you want to find only moons, you can also impose that `P` orbits around the `sun`

```
findall(X, (orbits(P, sun), orbits(X, P)), Lm)
```

or a clause as follows

```
allMoons(P, Lm) :-
  orbits(P, sun),
  findall(X, orbits(X, P), Lm).
```

or, with printing,

```
printAllMoons(P) :-
  orbits(P, sun),
  findall(X, orbits(X, P), Lm),
  write(Lm).
```

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP ask

> How would I combine it with `outer_orbit(P,O)` so that it will show all planets and its moons that are further away than `P`.

I suppose there are many ways.

If you want only print something and you want use `outer_orbit/2`, an example can be the following

```
printPlanetAndMoons(P1) :-
  write('- planet '), write(P1), nl,
  findall(X, orbits(X, P1), Lm),
  (     Lm \== []
     -> (write('   -- with moons '), write(Lm), nl)
     ;  true ).

printAllPlanetsAndMoonsMoreDistantThanAPlanet(P0) :-
  write('planets and moons more distant than '), write(P0), write(':'), nl,
  findall(P1, (outer_orbit(P0, P1), printPlanetAndMoons(P1)), _).
```

(hoping you can find better names for predicates).

Comment: hi, thanks. How would I combine it with `outer_orbit(P,O)` so that it will show all planets and its moons that are further away than P.

Comment: @Chris - answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. I changed it to `outer_orbit(P,O):-ae(O,X),ae(P,Y),X>Y,findall(P1, (outer_orbit(O,P1), listPlanet(P1)), _).` but this still only gets me the litst of planets. I am missing their moons as well.

Comment: @Chris - my example doesn't work? Anyway, what do exactly want to obtain with an `outer_orbit/2` that call itself in a `findall/3`?

Comment: it actually works like a charm. I was wondering if I could do this all together in just one outer_orbit(P,O) . I will mark your solution as complete. Thanks a lot for your effort.